# Apache web server: Serve multiple websites (not sub-domains) from port 80

Tags: webserver, apache-http-server

I am planning to make changes to Apache web server so that it can serve multiple websites (not sub-domains) from port 80.

This will save money for someone who has more than one website. That person need not buy more than one hosting plan, one hosting plan will suffice.

Based on the incoming base URL, Apache web server will decide from which directory to serve the index file or other files. There will be a user file where user can list which website is mapped to which directory.

For example:

```
abcd:com:/abcd
xyz.com:/xyz
```

I am not familiar with Apache web server code so can someone point me to few files which I need to modify to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu, your Apache2 installation will be in `/etc/apache2`, where you will have `sites-available` folder.
This folder should contain your `abcd.com.conf` and `xyz.com.conf` files, each pointing to their own directories